# VScode как изменить окно помощи синтаксиса

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, syntax

как в VScode изменить окно синтасиса? На первом скрине как выглядит у меня, на втором как нужно сделать. Мне просто не удобно что окошко такое маленькое, и то что оно вылазит снизу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Размер окошка автокомплита? Гм, мне кажется, что это настолько системная вещь, что она не кастомизируется. Или это для каждого языка просто разное количество строк в автокомплите и разная ширина, поэтому и подбирается автоматом.

Comment: @AK У человека в видео такой же язык как и у меня C#, но у него окошко современно другое

Comment: Тогда похоже какой-то пакет расширения установлен, но я не пишу код на c# в vscode (меня устраивает linqpad и visual studio), поэтому увы не подскажу. Попробуйте узнать у автора видео, может в комментариях к видео отпишется или поищите сами у него на канале может есть видео, где он показывает какие плагины ставит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Размер меняется растягиванием окошка за рамку.

Оно показывается сверху если снизу недостаточно места. Не уверен, что его можно показывать сверху всегда.